How do I balance having 484 in wisdom?
I'm playing as a set of two clerics, both with 22 in wisdom, and they just learned metamoran fusion from dragon ball, which can multiply their stats by each other. 22*22=484
How can I make this not obscenely overpowered in every sense of the word?
Their lowest stat, a  shared 10, still goes 70 points above what DND beyond even allows you to enter.

Is changing the rules for — or possibly even completely getting rid of — metamoran fusion an option?

Are we to assume that your wisdom modifier is now a +237?

From this, and all your other questions; I suggest you get your DM to actually read the PHB and DMG and start playing D&D instead of whatever game they think they are playing. Maybe you are all having fun, but you are absolutely not playing D&D.

@SeriousBri just for clarity (because I'm pretty sure that's what you mean): it's fine to play a game just for fun. Free-form RP is a thing for a reason. However, that is not really compatible with trying to balance things mechanically like this question here. Making such huge deviations to the rules is conflicts with then trying to add more rules to account for the deviations. If you intend to play a rules-grounded game, then houseruling should be light.

@VLAZ pretty much, thank you

You can’t
A Wisdom of 484 is auto-success on Wisdom ability checks and saving throws, and it means auto-failure of saving throws against any of your Wisdom-based DCs. Simply loading up on the most dangerous save-based spells available to you (which are ordinarily somewhat unreliable, or at least require careful targeting to apply to a save someone is poor at) means you can overcome any opposition of any kind anywhere.
To say nothing of all the other absurd stats that you have.
Quite simply, this is broken. The game is over; there is no challenge left aside from the inability to be in two places at once. Anything you try to do, you succeed at.
The only possible drawbacks that could prevent that result are those that prevent you from acting at all, or apply similarly-massive penalties that cancel out those numbers. You simply cannot be allowed to use numbers that high and expect there to be any balance or challenge left in the game. Trying to apply some other awful penalty, so that you have super-high ability scores but also have whatever other negative effect will not work: then you just get a situation where every single thing in the game is immediately siloed into one of just two categories: “things where my super-high stats allow me to automatically succeed,” and “things where my super-negative drawback prevents my stats from applying and which I simply cannot do at all.” Every possible interaction is one of these two things, and there can’t be anything else. That doesn’t leave any game left to play; the game simply is not designed for it.
D&D is not Dragon Ball. The way the numbers work in D&D are not the way numbers work in Dragon Ball; Goku’s power level was infamously “over 9,000!” and that’s not a number that fits anywhere in D&D—and that was relatively early on in Dragon Ball Z, in a franchise where the power escalation is memetically extreme. Having some custom effect that allows your characters to combine their strengths could be fine—D&D has even done stuff like that officially in the past—but copying the precise arithmetic that Dragon Ball uses is simply a mistake.

This glow up happens with all my stats, wisdom is just the most notable. The lowest stat of the merged fighter is 100

@Tasi You're not supposed to be able to get stats above 30 in D&D 5e, even for godlike beings.

@QuadraticWizard Good point.  it's in the PHB p.10 "30 - This is the highest a score can go".

@Tasi I’m aware, and mention that. There simply is no game left; the game is broken; the effect is game-breaking. The effect has to be something else in order to continue playing the game.

This answer - which I wholly agree with - could be improved by referring to the basic rules of D&D 5e 2024 which shows that the max ability score in the game is 30. (There's a table for that in the new PHB, but I don't have a link to the basic rules that I can get to right now).

To everyone pointing out the 30 maximum in the Player’s Handbook: I completely disagree that it’s in any way relevant here. This effect—if it were official—would be presumed an exception to that rule anyway, and even if you implement it, you still break the game. It’s not worth bringing up; at best, it’s irrelevant, and at worst, it’s a red herring.

@KRyan I agree. If we were talking about an ability score of 32, it's still over the cap but hardly the same as 484.

30 is the Maximum Ability Score
Page 10 of the 2024 PHB has a table called "Ability Scores" which clearly states that 30 is the highest a score can go. So my answer would be that your cleric's fused form would have godlike stats as follows:

Str 30
Dex 30
Con 30
Int 30
Wis 30
Cha 30

The reasoning here is that your characters' combined score isn't 22 * 22=484, it's Max(30, 22 * 22)=30, and since the lowest scores are 10, that puts everything at the maximum. Yes this is still pretty OP, but at least there's a chance that it isn't obscenely OP, as they still might fail a save or miss an attack.

If this was an official effect, and it said that scores are just set to the result of this calculation, I would understand that to be an exception to the 30 maximum, not having us perform a pointless calculation that always winds up being the maximum (unless you have paired scores that are both 5 or less—which I don’t think is actually possible in 5e—you’re going to hit 30). Moreover, all 30s would also be tremendously problematic. This focuses on the wrong things and doesn’t address the real issue.

@KRyan I see your point, but if someone instead asked, "Is this ability balanced?" I think many answers would point out the 30 stat-cap.  I don't think you're obligated to put it in your own answer, but nor do I think it's wrong to mention it.

@Novak It’s wrong if it is the only thing mentioned in the answer, as it is here.

Say "My bad" and retcon such a poorly designed rule.
The other option is to say "You win," and start a new campaign.
5e is a game with bonded accuracy so unlike other games (3.x) getting a +infinite sounds cool but is neither in the spirit of the game or its rules.

While it is certainly possible to achieve +∞ in 3.x, this answer makes it sound like it’s trivial, expected, or somehow not just as much “you win” as it is in 5e. This ability would be just as broken in 3.x as it is in 5e. Which is a shame, because other than the unnecessary pot shot, I thought this was a great answer.
